# No comma in text cite between name and parenthesis

Tags: biblatex, citing

When I use `\parencite` I have a comma between the surnames and the year but when I use `\textxite` I don't want that comma between the names and the parenthesis. How can I remove only the comma between the name and the comma when I use `\textcite`?

And in the bibliography the first name is surname, first name but the second name is first name surname. Is it possible to have first name surname and first name surname?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@BOOK{elch,
AUTHOR = "Karall, Benedikt and Schwarz, Markus",
TITLE = "{Eine Studie zur Elchplicht}",
PUBLISHER = "JG-Verlag",
YEAR = 2012}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

Die exakte Herleitung kann in \parencite[S.81]{elch} nachgelesen werden.
Die exakte Herleitung kann in \textcite[S.59]{elch} nachgelesen werden.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture]

edit...
I have installed the new update, but it won't work.... I don't know what overwriting bib.ref and missing csquotes is.... before the update it worked great...
[image]

edit...
csquotes is installed
[image]

Comment: The comma was a bug and will disappear if you update. For the sorting you can use `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you the names are know in the correct order and I installed the new updated but know the citations won't show...

Comment: Make sure that you update also biber. And delete the old bbl and recompile anew. The overwriting "ref.bib" is from your example - the filecontents always write a bib. The csquotes warning is harmless (but you should load csquotes).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It still shows overwriting ref.bib but know it works and I don't know why it shows missing csqquotes, because I have installed that package....

Comment: You may have installed csquotes but your document doesn't use it. Add \usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}.

Comment: Note that depending on the style `biblatex` adds the "pages" prefix automatically, so it is enough to use `\parencite[81]{elch}` instead of `\parencite[S.81]{elch}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in an old version of the package that has already been resolved in the current version, so the problem is solved by updating `biblatex` (and Biber with it, so the versions match).